# WordPress PHP current user info hiding a row

Tags: wordpress

I have a div in WordPress that is showing some of the current user info for someone who is logged in. The problem is, if the info is not there or the field is blank I want the entire row not to be shown, such as someones Middle Name. If the middle name is not there or is empty I want it to be show like this.

First Name: Blah

Last Name: Blahas

**and not**

First Name: Blah

Middle Name:

Last Name: Blahas

The code I have is

```
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'Relationship to Employee:' . $current_user->dep1_relationship . "\n";?><br>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'First Name:' . $current_user->dep1_firstname . "\n";?>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'Middle Name:' . $current_user->dep1_middlename . "\n";?>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'Last Name:' . $current_user->dep1_lastname . "\n";?><br>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'SSN:' . $current_user->dep1_social . "\n";?><br>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'Date of Birth:' . $current_user->dep1_dob . "\n";?><br>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'Gender:' . $current_user->dep1_gender . "\n";?><br>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'Student:' . $current_user->dep1_student . "\n";?><br>
<?php global $current_user;  get_currentuserinfo(); echo 'Add of Cancel:' . $current_user->dep1_addorcancelcoverage . "\n";?><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
<?php 
global $current_user;  
get_currentuserinfo(); 

echo ($current_user->dep1_relationship!='')?'Relationship to Employee: '.$current_user->dep1_relationship.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_firstname!='')?'First Name: '.$current_user->dep1_firstname.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_middlename!='')?'Middle Name: '.$current_user->dep1_middlename.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_lastname!='')?'Last Name: '.$current_user->dep1_lastname.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_social!='')?'SSN: '.$current_user->dep1_social.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_dob!='')?'Date of Birth: '.$current_user->dep1_dob.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_gender!='')?'Gender: '.$current_user->dep1_gender.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_student!='')?'Student: '.$current_user->dep1_student.'<br />':"";
echo ($current_user->dep1_addorcancelcoverage!='')?'Add of Cancel: '.$current_user->dep1_addorcancelcoverage.'<br />':"";
?>
```

Note you only need the following once...

```
global $current_user;  
get_currentuserinfo();
```